# Azure worker role - prevent recycling

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying something a little weird with the azure cloud service technology. I want to use the autoscaling for both up and down changes.

I'm going to have some instances that are "In Use" though.

Is there any way in a cloud service to either:
Mark an instance as non-recyclable
or
Abort the teardown of an instance in the WorkerRole.OnStop method

If not, what criteria does azure use to determine what gets recycled? Maybe I can keep the instance in a state where azure won't recycle it?

Thanks

Comment: Please see this blog post: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-right-way-to-handle-azure-onstop-events/. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. Both those articles appear to be about delaying recycling for ~5 minutes. I really need to be able to indefinitely deny the recycle.
I keep reading, but I'm not finding anything about how to do that (if you even can)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this, I can accomplish what I need to with Scale Sets
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machine-scale-sets-overview/

Answer (score 0):

See [Azure Compute Service worker becomes "busy" following scale-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271646/azure-compute-service-worker-becomes-busy-following-scale-up/25275563#25275563).  In short, your role instances should not be recycling during scaling operations.  If they are, then check the code in your Changing event per the link.